# Translate System.Drawing.KnownColor to ARGB

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to translate `[System.Drawing.KnownColor]` names to their ARGB values.

Here's the code I have so far. It's a modification to the code here:

https://learn-powershell.net/2013/03/07/translate-color-name-to-argb-using-powershell/

The original works for `[System.Drawing.Color]` but I cannot find a way to get the `KnownColor` translated.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

# Get-ARGBColor - https://learn-powershell.net/2013/03/07/translate-color-name-to-argb-using-powershell/
Function Get-ARGBColor {
  Param ([string[]]$Color)
  Begin
  {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
  }
  Process {
    If (-Not $PSBoundParameters['Color'])
    {
      $Colors = [System.Drawing.KnownColor] | Get-Member -static -MemberType Properties | Select -Expand Name
    }
    ForEach ($c in $color)
    {
      Try
      {
        $ARGB = [System.Drawing.KnownColor]$c
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          ARGB = "$([System.Drawing.KnownColor]::$c)"
          Colors = $c
        }
      }
      Catch {
        Write-Warning "$c is not a valid color"
      }
    }
  }
}

$colorKnownArr = [enum]::GetValues([System.Drawing.KnownColor]) | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Properties

Get-ARGBColor -Color $colorKnownArr[1].Name
```

Comment: As aside, shouldn't `$Colors` be `$Color` ?

Comment: `Colors = $c` you are referring to? Yes, that would make better sense.

Comment: No, I meant the variable `$Colors`. You are testing if parameter `$Color` has been given and if not, you define a further unused variable `$Colors`. Next you loop over `$Color` which is still empty then.. Anyway, I see @Daniel already provided the answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')

function Get-ARGBColor {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [System.Drawing.KnownColor]
        $Colors
    )

    process {
        foreach ($color in $Colors) {
            try {
                $drawingColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromKnownColor( $color)

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Color = $drawingColor.Name
                    aRGB  = '#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}' -f $drawingColor.A, $drawingColor.R, $drawingColor.G, $drawingColor.B
                }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "$color is not a valid color"

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Color = $color
                    aRGB  = 'not a valid color'
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. this is exactly what I was after. I may edit the post with an example of going through the system and known colours?

Comment: On further testing this is returning `Yellow = #FFFFFF0`. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: Hi @Ste - made a correction to the string formatting to pad with a 0.  Should work correctly now.

Comment: Thanks very much. [Here's the result.](https://i.imgur.com/B46F4k9.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to do so by using `[System.Drawing.Color]::FromName($ColorName)`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function Get-ARGBColor {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, HelpMessage = 'The name of the colour, Black, White etc.')]
    [System.Drawing.KnownColor]$ColorName
    )
  try {
    $drawingColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName($ColorName)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Color = $drawingColor.Name
      aRGB  = '#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}' -f $drawingColor.A, $drawingColor.R, $drawingColor.G, $drawingColor.B
    }
  }
  catch {
    Write-Warning "$ColorName is not a valid Color"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Color = $ColorName
      aRGB  = 'not a valid Color'
    }
  }
}

Get-ARGBColor -ColorName "Black"
# PS> Color aRGB
# PS> ----- ----
# PS> Black #FF000000

(Get-ARGBColor -ColorName "Black").Color
# PS> Black

(Get-ARGBColor -ColorName "White").aRGB
# PS> #FFFFFFFF

(Get-ARGBColor -ColorName "ActiveCaption").aRGB
# PS> #FF99B4D1
```